# Angular 2.2.0 deployment => require is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I am trying to deploy my Angular 2.2.0 solution with Gulp. I encouter the following issue that I wasn't able to solve until now despite that is the third project I am deploying.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at http://127.0.0.1/js/app.min.js:11:14

That targetting the following generated code for my application :

```
    var core_1 = require('@angular/core');
```

That's the only error message. 
Here is my **gulpfile.js**

```
    // Application dev
    gulp.task('app-bundle-dev', function () {
      var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

      //var tsResult = gulp.src(['node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts','app/**/*.ts'])
      var tsResult = gulp.src(['app/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(tsProject());

      return tsResult.js
        .pipe(addsrc.append('system.config.dev.js'))
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))    
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
    });

    // Deploy html templates
    gulp.task('html-templates', function () {
      return gulp.src("app/**/*.html")
        .pipe(rename({dirname: ''}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });

    // hammerjs
    gulp.task('hammerjs', function(){
      return gulp.src('node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
    });


    // shim
    gulp.task('shim', function(){
        return gulp.src([
            'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js.map',
            'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js'])
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
    });

    gulp.task('vendor-bundle', function() {
        gulp.src([        
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js',
            'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
            'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js'
            ])
            .pipe(concat('vendors.min.js'))
            //.pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
    });

    // Favicon
    gulp.task('favicon', function () {
        return gulp.src('favicon.ico')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
    });

    // CSS
    gulp.task('css', function () {
        return gulp.src('./css/*.css')
            .pipe(gulpif('*.css', cleanCss()))
            .pipe(concat('min.css'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
    });

    // Minify images
    gulp.task('img', function () {
        return gulp.src('images/**/*')
            .pipe(imageMin())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/images'));
    });

    // Angular scripts
    gulp.task('angular-bundle', function() {
        gulp.src([
            'node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.min.js',
            'node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.min.js',
            'node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.min.js',
            'node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.min.js',
            'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.min.js',
            'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js',
            'node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.min.js',
            'node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.min.js',
            'node_modules/@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
            'node_modules/@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js'
        ])
            //.pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
    });

    gulp.task('dev',['img','html-templates','hammerjs','vendor-bundle', 'angular-bundle', 'favicon', 'app-bundle-dev', 'shim', 'css'], function() {
        gulp.src('index.html')
            .pipe(htmlreplace({
                'es':'js/shim.min.js',
                'css': 'css/min.css',
                'vendor': 'js/vendors.min.js',
                'app': 'js/app.min.js',
                'hammerjs':'js/hammer.min.js'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
  {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "stripInternal": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "target": "es5"
      },
      "exclude": [
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser",
        "node_modules"
      ]
    }
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Sloter</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- build:css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/containers.css">
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

      </head>

      <body>
        <my-app>
          <img src="/images/logo.png" width="128px" height="auto" style="position:absolute;top:33%;left:50%;margin-left: -140px;" >
          <div height="auto" style="position:absolute;top:33%;width:2px;height:44px;left:50%;margin-left: -1px;background-color: #aaaaaa;">&nbsp;</div>
          <img src="/images/loader_small.gif" width="32px" height="auto" style="position:absolute;top:33%;left:50%;margin-left: 32px;" >
          <img src="/images/mooke_logo.png" width="128px" height="auto" style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin-left: -64px;" >
        </my-app>

        <!-- build:hammerjs -->
        <script src="node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:es -->
        <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:vendor -->    
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>    
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:app -->
        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

**system.config.dev.js**

```
System.config({
      map: {
        '@angular/core': 'http://127.0.0.1/js/core.umd.min.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'http://127.0.0.1/js/compiler.umd.min.js',
        '@angular/common': 'http://127.0.0.1/js/common.umd.min.js',
        '@angular/http': 'http://127.0.0.1/js/http.umd.min.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'http://127.0.0.1/js/platform-browser.umd.min.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'http://127.0.0.1/js/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js',
        '@angular/router': 'http://127.0.0.1/js/router.umd.min.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'http://127.0.0.1/js/forms.umd.min.js',
        '@angular/upgrade': 'http://127.0.0.1/js/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
        'hammerjs': 'http://127.0.0.1/js/hammer.min.js'
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      System.import('main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    });
```

My first idea was that a library was missing. But that seems that I was wrong.

Thanks !

**UPDATE 1**

After a few investigations, I discover that my generated code doesn't looks like usually. The components are registered like that

```
System.register(['@angular/core'], function(exports_1, context_1)
```

When there was generated like below in my previous (with Angular RC5) solutions :

```
System.register("app.component", ['@angular/core'], function(exports_1, context_1)
```

Why is the name of the component isn't included in the parameters of the **System.register** function ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your ts.config, I found changing module from commonjs to system fixed it on my angular 2 project.

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "stripInternal": true,
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "target": "es5"
      },
      "exclude": [
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser",
        "node_modules"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Tx for the answer. I've tried and now I have the following error : `vendors.min.js:4003 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid System.register call. Anonymous System.register calls can only be made by modules loaded by SystemJS.import and not via script tags.`

Comment: Are you using Firebug, a quick look at SystemJS's bug list shows this error being related to Firebug and may be fixable by setting

Comment: Oops hit enter :) By setting globalEvaluationScope: false

Comment: Doesn't work better. That seems to have no effect. Ouch ! Painfull deployments :/

Comment: I'm going to assume that system js can find your files on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes,they are all well deployed. I have check

Comment: Once again, no answer :/

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to resolve the second issue you have. I don't have much experience using SystemJS I tend to pretty much exclusively use Webpack.

Comment: No problem. Most of the documentation that we can found on the web only talk about what we can learn with tutorials. For exemple, there is no articles on "how to deploy Angular 2.2 + gulp + systemJS ?". I work on a the deployment of my solution since 4 days and it's just the hell if you want to do it properly.